# What legal recourse does Huawei have to have the U.S. remove it from their blacklist?

Tags: international, security

https://www.ft.com/content/978f169a-8175-11e9-b592-5fe435b57a3b

> China has lashed out at the US over its blacklisting of Huawei,
> accusing it of abusing national security exceptions to global trade
> rules during a tense meeting at the World Trade Organization.

I am wondering if Huawei has any legal recourse it can take to challenge the U.S. government in court. I am wondering, because it seems like a national security issue and if treated as such I don't think a legal recourse from Huawei is even possible. Is it the case, or is it more complicated than it seems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for Huawei to sue in US courts for relief, they would have to overcome the clear statutory basis of the relevant [presidential orders](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/presidential-actions/2021/06/03/executive-order-on-addressing-the-threat-from-securities-investments-that-finance-certain-companies-of-the-peoples-republic-of-china/). There is no believable story where either Trump or Biden exceeded their statutory and constitutional authority – that is a dead end. Then you might imagine that there could be some treaty to which the US is party, which somehow prohibits blacklisting Huawei. But there is e.g. no US-China free trade treaty. You might think that perhaps there is some WTO rule that prohibits blacklisting. Even if there were, WTO rules are subordinate to US law. The [Uruguay Round Agreements Act](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/19/3512) states that

> No provision of any of the Uruguay Round Agreements, nor the
> application of any such provision to any person or circumstance, that
> is inconsistent with any law of the United States shall have effect.

So we're back to the fact that Congress passed a law which allows POTUS to make this determination and do what he did (2 presidents did). The [statutory authorization](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/50/1701) is broadly about a national emergency w.r.t. a threat "to the national security, foreign policy, or economy of the United States", not limited to national security.